# SQLite - preferable encoding for windows platform

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, sqlite, utf-16

I develop c++ app for Windows.

I will use SQLite 3 to store:

- paths to different files on HDD
- strings from the GUI interface (originally for such strings may be used any encoding - English, Spanish, Chinese, etc.)
- different ASCII strings

I would like to have UNIQUE index on the column with filepath strings. But it's not required - I can do it by my c++ code.

What encoding should I use - UTF-8, UTF-16le or UTF-16be ?

---

P.S.
SQLite has 3 functions to open DB: `sqlite3_open`, `sqlite3_open16`, `sqlite3_open_v2`.
Seems that for Windows I have to use `sqlite3_open16` because path may contain non-ACSII symbols. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use UTF-8, which is the default.

The various UTF-16 encodings waste space (except when the vast majority of text in the DB is non-ASCII), which requires more I/O, which makes everything slower.
Furthermore, most `16` functions convert their parameters from/to UTF-8 and then call an internal function that uses UTF-8, so they will always be slower.

While functions with `16` in their name receive and return UTF-16 strings, this is independent of the database's actual encoding (all functions convert from/to UTF-8 or UTF-16 as required).

Functions *without* `16` use UTF-8, which is just a different encoding. The set of characters you can use is exactly the same in both cases, and the SQL always behaves the same.

Some functions (e.g., `sqlite3_open_v2`) are not available in a `16` version.

Using the `16` functions makes sense only if you are forced to use UTF-16 strings for other reasons, and would have to convert anyway.

Comment: 'the only way to set the encoding of a database is PRAGMA encoding.'  Not so, the default encoding is determined when a new database is created "The default encoding will be UTF-8 for databases created using sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open_v2(). The default encoding for databases created using sqlite3_open16() will be UTF-16 in the native byte order."  https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html.

Comment: Regarding wasted space. Cyrillic, Chinese, Japanese and Hindi characters occupy 30% more space in UTF-8 than in UTF-16.

Comment: @rustyx: false, Cyrillic is 2 bytes per char in both UTF-16 and UTF-8. See also utf8everywhere.org.

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at the upcoming UTF-8 revision, FSS-UTF.

Comment: Since you proposed this question as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38814198/1889329), and failed to answer that other question, I'm forced to downvote this answer. Don't blame me for framing you like this. Go blame yourself.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-16le

Since the windows API uses this internally, if you use anything else then every windows API call will have the overhead of doing the conversions.  If you have lot of windows API calls with long string, this might become significant.

It is not a big deal in most cases.  I recommend choosing one, and then focussing energy and time on other issues that have a greater impact.

---

"Seems that for Windows I have to use sqlite3_open16 because path may contain non-ACSII symbols"

Yes.  This will also set the defaultencoding in the DB to UTF16.  https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: Performance is not a concern. I care about data integrity - do not want get corrupted data or failed search due to conversion issues ))  I've found info that internally SQLite uses UTF-8 and converts all sqls to the UTF-8. Does it impact on the SQLite functionality?

Comment: You don't have to use `sqlite3_open16` on Windows. If you are using one of the narrow string API calls to open a database, make sure to pass a UTF-8 encoded filename. UTF-8 and UTF-16 can encode identical character sets.